# CollectionViewCells are being mixed with each other

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hello fellow overflowers so I set up a collectionView and configure it but when I run the simulator I get a lot of cells just mixed with each other like in the first picture.

I have added the identifier at the storyboards cell also created the class for the cell but I can't seem to know what the problem might be since it never happened.

How I want my cell to be I will show on the second picture.

[first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AGu9.png)

[second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fclBn.png)

the code:

```
extension dashboardViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return 15
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "dashboardCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? dashboardCollectionViewCell else {return UICollectionViewCell()}
    
    return cell
  }
}
```

Comment: It does not seem like it's getting mixed but more like it's getting cut off. This seems to me like a size issue (more specifically a width issue) for your collection view cells. If you are using flow layout, try setting the item size.

Comment: Check your Auto-Layout for dashboardCollectionViewCell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the image provided, it seems you haven't set the item size of the cell
in horizontal layout as well as the minimum spacing between each cell. You can do that (set item size) by calling

```
func collectionView(
  _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
  layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
  sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath
) -> CGSize {}
```

this method from `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.
You can also do this using storyboard.
[Size Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQJDL.png)

Comment: Thanks based on your comment and image I managed to fix it through the Size at the Inspector :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your collection view cell's size has not correct set.
If your are using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, maybe you can check the layout object's `itemSize` property.

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

...

// Set a suitable CGSize for the `itemSize` property
// In this example I set it to 100pt * 50pt
layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(100, 50);

...

UICollectionView *collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:layout];
```

Comment: Hey I want to use it Horizontal cells, and the layout is of type Flow.

Comment: @LisTahirbegolli it's ok to use UICollectionViewFlowLayout to Horizontal cells. But if the layout object's `itemSize` property is not correct set, the cell will small than you expectation. You can set a larger itemSize for the layout object.